# IE10 is out, they talk about 'Web Workers' which offload long-running JS out of the webpage into a seperate worker, Does Google Chrome have this?

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, web-worker

Does Google Chrome do something like what they're describing in IE10? Or is Chrome lacking here? or is it different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Firefox has had Web Workers since version 3.5
- Chrome has had Web Workers since version 3
- Opera has had Web Workers since version 10.60

Internet Explorer was the last of the major browsers to implement Web Workers.

Comment: WOW, this is why I hate IE, they always make it seem like they've just done something no one else has. They phrase things to try to trick you... Dam*it I really don't like IE now...

Comment: Internet Explorer is *never* at the forefront of implementation of new standards. Proponents of Internet Explorer will argue that this is due to Microsoft not wanting to support 'moving target' standards that aren't quite finished, but I don't believe this is a valid argument.

Comment: so versions IE<10 do not have web workers at all? any workaround possible?